# Why element.classList.add('class-name'); is not working?

Tags: javascript

Have HTML (part):

```
<div class="modal-write-us">
  <form class="modal-write-us-form" action="" method="post">
    <label>
      <input type="text" name="user-name" required>
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="text" name="e-mail" required>
    </label>
    <label for="text-field"></label>
    <textarea name="text" rows="5" id="text-field" required></textarea>
  </form>
  <div class="modal-write-us-button">
    <button class="btn btn-red" type="submit">Submit</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

I need to add class "modal-error" for div.modal-write-us if submitted form have empty field/fields.

JS:

```
var modalWriteUs = document.querySelector('.modal-write-us');
var form = modalWriteUs.querySelector('form');
var userName = modalWriteUs.querySelector('[name=user-name]');
var eMail = modalWriteUs.querySelector('[name=e-mail]');
var textArea = modalWriteUs.querySelector('[name=text]');

form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
  if (!userName.value || !eMail.value || !textArea.value) {
    event.preventDefault();
    modalWriteUs.classList.add('modal-error');
  }
});
```

But class is not added. Where is my mistake?

Comment: are you sure you are making it through that condition? add a console.log to verify

Comment: @Lina You need quotation marks in your CSS attribute selectors. For example: `modalWriteUs.querySelector('[name="user-name"]');`

Comment: @Nayuki The values of attribute selectors can be identifiers too.

Comment: Use Chrome Debugger to spot the issue, that's exactly what it's made are for.

Comment: The main problem is that the submit button element isn't inside of the `form` element. This means that the form won't be submitted when clicking the button. You also need to make sure you're running the JS after the DOM loads. In addition, you may also need to add the `novalidate` attribute to the `form` element in order to prevent default validation -> https://jsfiddle.net/nmn4w3p1/

Comment: @RobM. yes, i tried it through console. Class is not adding.

Comment: The form will not submit.

Comment: @JoshCrozier Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you put `<button class="btn btn-red" type="submit">Submit</button>` inside the `<form>` it should work.

See working [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/ZzXDg55fp4YfFeKvB8iE?p=preview).

```
<div class="modal-write-us">
  <form class="modal-write-us-form" action="" method="post">
    <label>
      <input type="text" name="user-name" required>
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="text" name="e-mail" required>
    </label>
    <label for="text-field"></label>
    <textarea name="text" rows="5" id="text-field" required></textarea>
    <div class="modal-write-us-button">
      <button class="btn btn-red" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

**EDIT:** More explanation [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.2.1):

> The elements used to create controls generally appear **inside a FORM** element, but may also appear outside of a FORM element declaration when they are used to build user interfaces. This is discussed in the section on intrinsic events. Note that controls outside a form cannot be successful controls.

Comment: You might want to explain why.

Comment: Thanks! I put <button> inside the <form> and delete attribute 'required' from <input>/<textarea> and code work now.

Comment: Would appreciate constructive criticism, since we have some 'negativity' :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to place your submit button into the form.
Then, change submit button to input:

```
<input class="btn btn-red" type="submit">Submit</input>
```

Now you need to make some fixes in your JS.
Use double quotes in atttribute selectors:

```
querySelector('[name="user-name"]')
```

Attribute `required` doesn't allow to submit empty form, so your submit callback never runs.
If you remove `required` attribute your code will work.